# Django REST Framework make asynchronous request to respond

Tags: django, web-services, rest, asynchronous, celery

I implemented a Django REST API using Django Rest Framework.

For this API I have to call 3 http web services and I merge the data results like response of my API.

So, I have:

```
- Request WS 1
- Request WS 2
- Request WS 3
--> RESULT = Merge Results 1, 2, 3
----> Response: RESULT
```

Is it possible to have Request WS 1, 2,3 as asynchronous requests?

Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 16):

Its not a good idea to use threads to do that, threading adds more complexity and could be hard to debug.
In that case of situation you could use a task scheduler (Celery, Django-RQ, etc). You have to choose one based on your system. Celery is well-known but could be too much for your system.

I recommend to approach this using HTTP statuses and some basic payload.
The idea is to get the request, send the "get to third party sites task" to the task scheduler and return a "polling URL" with status 202.
By "Polling URL" I mean an API endpoint, where the user could check the status of the task.
HTTP Status 202 tells the user that the request has been accepted but the processing has not finished (its async).

Then the callee of the API could poll the "polling URL" every X times, to fetch the task's result.
Example:

```
def api_process_request(request):
    data = process_data(request)
    polling_url = send_task_to_scheduler(data)
    return JsonResponse({'url': polling_url}, status=202)

def api_polling_url(request, task_id):
    done, result = task_scheduler_get_result(task_id)
    return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'status': done}, status=200)
```

Hope it helps you!
Good luck :)

Comment: I love celery, but how is using celery, or something similar, like this easier and less complex than simply using threads? One could argue that going multi-process and spinning up an async distributed task queue for such a simple use case "adds more complexity and could be hard to debug" as well.

Comment: @Sean, sure no problem.
If you spawn a thread on every request you could end doing a DOS attack against your own application by consuming your resources.
Generally the web server will launch few 'workers' which will be in charge of running Django and listen for requests.If you spawn threads inside the workers (your views or other django component), which are running the Django stack, the thread will inherit everything from Django (they share the memory space), which most of the time is not what you want.

Comment: @Sean, Other drawback I see doing threading inside the requests-response cycle is you end forcing more 'context-switching' to the Kernel because Python's thread are mapped to System Thread  then the kernel would have to schedule them, they are expensive as well.
The same idea applies to processes with the difference that you are calling to fork() syscall which will run your code in a brand new Python Interpreter.
Thanks!

Comment: @Martin great answers! I wasn't thinking about how crazy things might get when using mutiple workers (I should have since that's the most common pattern). I'm with you now - celery ftw :)